How to get PID of running sh script if I run process in background there?
I wish to ping my router in background process. Also I want to control ping process as a service: start, status, stop. So, I create lock file and store PID in it. But actually PID is changing, and I cannot kill my process. I store PID with variable $$, but it changing, I don't know why, may be because I run pipe or may be I run process in background? Could you advise me, how to get PID in sh script, where I run pipe in background?
Code of my sh script ping.sh:$ cat ping.sh
#!/bin/sh


option=$1

if [ "$option" = "start" ]; then
  if [ -f /tmp/ping.lock ]; then
    echo There is another ping process. Exit
    exit 1
  else
    touch /tmp/ping.lock
    (ping 192.168.1.1 | ts | tee -a >> ~/1) &
    echo $$ > /tmp/ping.lock ##here i store script pid
  fi

elif [ "$option" = "status" ]; then
  if [ -f /tmp/ping.lock ]; then
    echo ping is running. PID:
    cat /tmp/ping.lock
  else
    echo ping is not running
  fi

elif [ "$option" = "stop" ]; then
  if [ -f /tmp/ping.lock ]; then
    echo killing ping process
    kill $(cat /tmp/ping.lock)
    echo removing lock file
    rm /tmp/ping.lock
    echo ping stopped.
  else
    echo ping is not running.
  fi

else
  echo Usage: $0 [start, status, stop]
fi

Actually line echo $$ > /tmp/ping.lock ##here i store script pid does not store actual PID, but that pid that is stores disappears. And this call does not kill my script:
$ ./ping.sh 
Usage: ./ping.sh [start, status, stop]
$ ./ping.sh start
There is another ping process. Exit
$ rm /tmp/ping.lock 
$ 
$ ./ping.sh start
$ ps -ef | grep ping
y         5271  2221  1 19:36 ?        00:00:10 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --show-component-extension-options --enable-gpu-rasterization --no-default-browser-check --disable-pings --media-router=0 --enable-remote-extensions --load-extension
y         5993  4075  0 19:44 pts/2    00:00:00 vim ping.sh
y         6089     1  0 19:45 pts/5    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./ping.sh start
y         6090  6089  0 19:45 pts/5    00:00:00 ping 192.168.1.1
y         6095  5241  0 19:45 pts/5    00:00:00 grep ping
$ 
$ cat /tmp/ping.lock 
6087
$ 
$ ./ping.sh stop
killing ping process
./ping.sh: 27: kill: No such process

removing lock file
ping stopped.
$ 
$ ps -ef | grep ping
y         5271  2221  1 19:36 ?        00:00:10 /usr/lib/chromium/chromium --show-component-extension-options --enable-gpu-rasterization --no-default-browser-check --disable-pings --media-router=0 --enable-remote-extensions --load-extension
y         5993  4075  0 19:44 pts/2    00:00:00 vim ping.sh
y         6089     1  0 19:45 pts/5    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./ping.sh start
y         6090  6089  0 19:45 pts/5    00:00:00 ping 192.168.1.1
y         6148  5241  0 19:46 pts/5    00:00:00 grep ping

As you can see, after calling ./ping.sh stop there is still process of my script and its PID is 6089, while in lock file stored PID 6087. How to get PID 6089 stored in lock file? When and how to store it?

Are you looking for $!?
(ping 192.168.1.1 | ts | tee -a >> ~/1) & pid=$!; echo "$pid" > tmp/pid_prev_bg_cmd.txt

Captures the PID of the previous command that used &.

$0......The name of the script being executed.
$1-9..The first nine command-line arguments.
$#......The number of command-line arguments.
$*......All command-line arguments as a single string.
$@......All command-line arguments as an array.
$?......The exit status of the last executed command.
$$......The process ID of the current shell.
$!.....The process ID of the last background command.


Why do you initialize a variable with the value of the parameter $!?

@qqqq It's a special variable that gives the PID of the last background command.

I understand, however, I meant why don't you just print the value of the parameter without a variable assignment (i.e. pid=$!)

@qqqq I don't really remember why I always do that with a variable.  I want to say it was something I learned years and years ago about syntax and semantics.  It's "safer" practice, I believe.

yes, copying variable is the simplest and should be done before any echo to file, and may be initializing pipe or something that will actually change $! value
